# I can't attach html file while using emayili

Tags: html, email, rstudio, attachment

I'm trying to send an e-mail using package emayili and I need to attach an html file. The code runs well and I receive the e-mail, but the file never goes attached. I've been searching and changing my code, but it is always a dead end.

Here is my code:

```
     email <- envelope() %>%
      from("1234@gmail.com") %>%
      to("1234@gmail.com") %>%
      subject("subject") %>%
      body("text")
    files<-xml2::read_html(paste("D:/path/file",".html",sep=""))
    email <- email %>% attachment(files)
smtp <- server(host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               port = 465,
               username = "1234@gmail.com",
               password = "pass")
smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

also tried

```
email <- email %>% attachment(read_html(paste("D:/path/file",".html",sep="")))
```

and several other things...

Any advice?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try sending to a non-gmail domain email and see if the attachment comes. I just noticed that the attachment comes to a different domain but my Gmail account doesn't receive it. (Trying to send a .nb.html output from R.)